# how to customize filament default dashboard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

As per filament documentation created a new file at app/Filament/Pages/Dashboard.php and also remove the original Dashboard class from filament.php

Dashboard.php File Code:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/39INc.png)

filament.php File Code:

```
'pages' => [
        'namespace' => 'App\\Filament\\Pages',
        'path' => app_path('Filament/Pages'),
        'register' => [],
    ],
```

After following these steps, I am facing these issues getting the Dashboard option multiple times in the sidebar.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVf36.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize your Filament default Dashboard.php as follows...
Create a custom page using

`php artisan make:filament-page Dashboard`

- it will generate a view file and a Dashboard class.
- to add a default Widget in the dashboard widgets

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use App\Filament\Widgets;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Pages\Dashboard as BasePage;

class Dashboard extends BasePage
{
    protected function getWidgets(): array
    {
        // return default widgets
        return Filament::getWidgets();
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to add addition details then you can constomize page as per your requirement.
https://filamentphp.com/tricks/how-to-customize-dashboard-page

Comment: Note this won't work with Filament 3, which has substantial changes.

Answer (score 6):

If the accepted answer doesn't works for you because it didn't worked for me, you can go to your Filament Service Provider file and find the following code in it

```
->widgets([
            Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
            Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class,
        ])
```

You can comment out both or any of them to disable these widgets displaying on your default filament Dashboard, It will work.

Default File path in laravel will be: `app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php`

Comment: Works with Filament 3 :-) (and not actually explained in the Filament docs yet.)